# trouble with solving knapsack issue recursively in C

Tags: c, recursion, knapsack-problem

I need to solve the knapsack problem recursively, memoized and with dynamic programming. Currently I'm stuck at the recursive method.

The issue is that I'm not actually sure whether my code is doing what it's supposed to (and I'm not sure how to check, either). I adapted the code from what I found elsewhere on the internet.

The problem involves profit and mass. Each item has a profit and mass associated, there is a MAX_N (umber) of items available and a MAX_CAPACITY for mass. The aim is to have as much "profit" in the knapsack as possible.

Here is the complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX(x, y) (((x) > (y)) ? (x) : (y))
#define MIN(x, y) (((x) < (y)) ? (x) : (y))

#define MAX_N 10
#define MAX_CAPACITY 165

int m[MAX_N][MAX_CAPACITY];

int knapsackRecursive(int capacity, int mass[], int profit[], int n) {
    if (n < 0)
        return 0;
    if (profit[n] > capacity)
        return knapsackRecursive(capacity, mass, profit, n-1);
    else
        return MAX(knapsackRecursive(capacity, mass, profit, n-1), knapsackRecursive(capacity - mass[n], mass, profit, n-1) + profit[n]);
}

int knapsackMemoized(int capacity, int mass[], int profit[], int n) {

}

int knapsackDynamic(int capacity, int mass[], int profit[], int n) {

}

void test() {

    int M1[4] = {6, 3, 2, 4};
    int P1[4] = {50, 60, 40, 20};

    int M2[10] = {23, 31, 29, 44, 53, 38, 63, 85, 89, 82};
    int P2[10] = {92, 57, 49, 68, 60, 43, 67, 84, 87, 72};

    // a)
    knapsackRecursive(MAX_CAPACITY, M1, P1, MAX_N);
    knapsackRecursive(MAX_CAPACITY, M2, P2, MAX_N);

    // b)
    knapsackMemoized(MAX_CAPACITY, M1, P1, MAX_N);
    knapsackMemoized(MAX_CAPACITY, M2, P2, MAX_N);

    // c)
    knapsackDynamic(MAX_CAPACITY, M1, P1, MAX_N);
    knapsackDynamic(MAX_CAPACITY, M2, P2, MAX_N);

}

int main() {
    test();
}
```

As I have mentioned, I'm not actually sure how I would check whether the calculation is correct in the first place (as in, where to insert debug `printf()`'s). I tried printing the end result of M1 / P1 and that resulted in "170" which I don't think is correct.

EDIT: Here is an example provided by the exercise:

> Example: Given a knapsack of capacity 5, and items with mass[] = {2, 4, 3, 2}
>   and profit profit[] = {45, 40, 25, 15}, the best combination would be item 0 (with mass 2 and profit 45) and item 2 (with mass 3 and with profit 25) for a total profit of 70. No other combination with mass 5 or less has a greater profit.

Comment: Shouldn't `if (profit[n] > capacity)` be `if (mass[n] > capacity)`?

Comment: that is a very good point. Yes, that should probably be the case but I don't think it's the only problem in the code.

Comment: You can test it with easy to calculate values.

Comment: Yeah, I just tested it with the example's values that were provided (see edit in original post) and it looks like the code outputs the correct value now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program is incorrect, see this line:

```
if (profit[n] > capacity)
    return knapsackRecursive(capacity, mass, profit, n-1);
```

Here you compare profit with capacity. You should compare with `mass[n]`. The rest of the code looks ok for now.

Perhaps you better use the maximum of a library and not the "ternary operator", since such operator creates branches whereas sometimes maximum can be done without branching.

A problem with the program you can perhaps try to resolve is at least generate the bag and print it. You can also use instance of the Knapsack problem with a known solution.

Comment: I wasn't aware C had built-in max() operators. How would I use it?

Comment: @enenra: sorry, it's not builtin. But this [code](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerMinOrMax) shows how to do it without any branching.

Comment: oh, thanks! So I assume I can just normally implement that as a function, yes? Also, I just tested it with an example that was provided (see edit in original post) and the algorithm seems to now output the correct number.